# Concatenating adjacent rows with Excel power query

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

Suppose I have a power query in Excel that produces data like this:

```
Col1      Col2      Col3
Item11    Item12    Item13
Item21    Item22    Item23
Item31    Item32    Item33
Item41    Item42    Item43
```

and I want to join consecutive rows in pairs using another power query:

```
Col1A      Col2A      Col3A      Col1B      Col2B      Col3B
Item11     Item12     Item13     Item21     Item22    Item23
Item31     Item32     Item33     Item41     Item42    Item43
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Your table is `4x3` and your result is `2x6`. Will there always be three columns and an even number of rows?  If your table has six rows (6x3) would output be `3x6`?

Comment: Yes, that would be the result of pairwise joining six rows of three columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the following should work:

- Group by pairs using Table.Group
- Flatten each pair into a single row by

  - Unpivot to two columns
  - Put the correct column names into the Attribute column
  - Pivot back on the Attribute column

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table8"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col1", type text}, {"Col2", type text}, {"Col3", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], 2), Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division",{"Index"}),
    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Integer-Division"}, {
        {"Flatten", (t)=>let 
            #"Unpivot" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table.RemoveColumns(t,"Integer-Division"),{},"Columns","Values"),
            #"Add Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivot","Index"),
            #"Integer-Div" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Index","IntDiv", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], Table.RowCount(#"Add Index")/2)),
            #"Rem Index" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Integer-Div","Index"),
            #"Col Names" = Table.AddColumn(#"Rem Index","ColNames", each [Columns] & "_" & Character.FromNumber([IntDiv] + 65)),
            #"Rem Cols" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Col Names",{"Columns","IntDiv"}),
            #"Pivot" = Table.Pivot(#"Rem Cols", #"Rem Cols"[ColNames], "ColNames", "Values")

            in 
                #"Pivot"
            
            }}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Integer-Division"}),
    #"ColNames" = Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns1"{0}[Flatten]),
    #"Expanded Flatten" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Flatten", 
        #"ColNames"),

    #"Set Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Flatten", 
        List.Transform(#"ColNames", each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Set Types"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have to give this some study but at a quick read-through, added to the fact that it gave the right result, it looks like my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're looking for something more than just the concatenate feature but if not... that's what I'm thinking of. If we assume:

- Col1 starts at A
- Col1A starts at G.

As an example i put a two spaces and dash in between to separate the inputs from the different cells.

```
=CONCAT(A2," - ",G2)
```

That would give a result of "Item11 - Item11"

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, but I believe you're thinking of worksheet functions. I'm asking in the context of Excel power queries. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-power-query-in-excel-7104fbee-9e62-4cb9-a02e-5bfb1a6c536a.